# Can you own a fractional portion of a kitplane or experimental airplane?

Tags: experimental-aircraft

I understand that experimental/kit planes can't be used for 'training for hire', i.e. an option of leasing them to flight schools is out. But... is it possible to own such aircraft on the fractional basis? Is there anything in regulations that would prevent me from holding, let's say, a 1/4 ownership of a Sling 4?

Comment: Which country's regulations are you asking about?

Comment: There is no rule against that.  As far as the FAA is concerned, at least.

Comment: Yes, at least in the United States, there is no problem doing this and quite a few aircraft clubs do exactly that.

Comment: Yes, I meant in the US. Sorry for not being specific. I'm glad to hear that the clubs take advantage of it. Thank you for all your responses.